# Variadic template and std::array unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdarray

I can compile but I have problems in running the following code (I minimized it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


template<int N>
class Selector {

public:

    template <typename... Args>
    Selector(int x, Args... args) noexcept {
        integers[sizeof...(Args)] = x;
        std::cout << "integers[" << sizeof...(Args) << "]=" << integers[sizeof...(Args)] << std::endl;  // OK

        Selector(args...);
    }

    Selector(int x) noexcept {
        integers[0] = x;
        std::cout << "integers[0]=" << integers[0] << std::endl;    // OK
    }


    void print_num(int i) const {
        std::cout << "integers[" << i << "]=" << integers[i] << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::array<int, N> integers;
};

int main() {
    Selector<3> x(5, 10, 15);

    x.print_num(2); // OK
    x.print_num(1); // KO
    x.print_num(0); // KO

}
```

The output is:

```
integers[2]=5
integers[1]=10
integers[0]=15
integers[2]=5
integers[1]=1016039760
integers[0]=22034
```

Clearly the first two cells of the array have garbage numbers after the object initialization. I suspect that I'm corrupting the stack in some way, but I cannot figure out why/where...

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not indexing 3, because sizeof...(Args) <= 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `Selector(args...);` in the constructor, just constructs a temporary object which gets destroyed immediately; it does nothing relevent to the current object.

I suppose you want [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) (since C++11):

```
template <typename... Args>
Selector(int x, Args... args) noexcept : Selector(args...) {
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    integers[sizeof...(Args)] = x;
    std::cout << "integers[" << sizeof...(Args) << "]=" << integers[sizeof...(Args)] << std::endl;  // OK
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wsRdRGsC3WtP4LAt)

Comment: @RicoRico You might be confusing with Java; which seems to be able to do that (I'm not sure even).

Comment: This is the first time I use a variadic template in a constructor and well... I used it like I do for a function call eheh...

Comment: @RicoRico I see. Yes `Selector(args...);` would call the constructor but it just has nothing to do with the current object.